# Finding a closed form expression for a given recursice sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on the following exercise:

> Suppose a sequence $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ satisfies the following equation system:
>
> $$x_i = \frac{x_{i+1}+x_{i-1}}{2} \quad \text{ (for  $2 \le i \le k$)}$$
> $$x_1 = \frac{x_2+1}{2}$$
> $$x_{k+1} = 0.$$
>
> Show that $$x_i = \max \bigg\{1-\frac{i}{k+1}, 0 \bigg\}\quad  \text{(for $i \le k+1$)}.$$

I do not understand how I am supposed to prove this. I tried to start with $x_k$ and using the recursive identity and the fact that $x_{k+1} = 0$, but it led nowhere. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Kindly check if the question is correct. The identity that you wish to prove - it is not clear how to prove it even for $i = 1$, as the RHS involves $k + 1$. In the recurrence relation for $x_1$, $x_2$, etc., we don't see '$k$' in it..

Comment: The solution doesn't satisfy $x_1 = (x_2 + 1) / 2$. Can you check your question again?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The question as it stands is correct (at least according to my sheet). If it helps, the sheet gives the hint to introduce $x_0 = 1$, but I do not see how this could help here...